# How to check the host server supports the ResumeData

Tags: ios, swift, server, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

How to check the host server supports the ResumeData ?

I have a file to download from server and perform pause and resume operations, I want to know is there any dependence on server side, that its supports **ResumeDate** or not.

If yes then how should I confirmed that host server supports **ResumeData**

ThankYou
Your inputs will helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

it could go something this like

// in pseudocode as I don't know how you have parsed this out

```
func doesResume() -> Bool {

    var truth : Bool = false

    if (server.resumeData) {
        truth = true
        print("does support ResumeData")
    } else {
        print("does not support ResumeData")
    }

    return truth
}
```

with something like you could use the Bool value for the testing of resume, but you will have to recode the

```
server.resumeData
```

to whatever connection you are using such as

```
Firebase.Auth().auth.resumeData
```

... etc